# How to use docstrings or similar in Visual Studio Python developement

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have a Python Project and unfortunately I have to do it in Visual Studio 2022.

How do I create good documentation?
Are there any external tools like for doxygen?

docstrings seem good, but I hope there is a way I do not have to write everything out all the time. Are there any shortcuts to create fast docstrings?